# onLoadComplete not working with AS2 SWF loaded via AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript-2

So I have run into an issue and I think it is mostly because I haven't worked with as2 in about 5 years so things are pretty hazy. Anyway, my problem is that I need to display PDF files within the flash movie. To do so I have resorted to running SWFTools in my backend and converting pdfs to swf for display. SWFTools, though, outputs AS2 files which I can load into AS3 but I can't actually control (for example, calling stop()).

Thus I have resorted to using an AS2 loader which gets loaded into the AS3 project which is responsible for loading the converted pdf swfs. The problem I am running into is that the listener does not seem to be firing when I load the AS2 file in via AS3 but it fires just fine when run on it's own.

This is the code I am running. To summarize when I run this code on it's own "LOADED" correctly prints to the output and the loaded SWF stops. However, when I run it via an AS3 container the swf loads in correctly but the "LOADED" trace never occurs and the stop is not executed.

thanks so much for any help!

```
var loader:MovieClipLoader

var listener =  new Object();
listener.onLoadComplete = function(loadedClip) {
    trace("LOADED");
    loadedClip.stop();
}

loadFile("data/testing.swf");

function loadFile(target){
    loader = new MovieClipLoader();
    loader.addListener(listener);
    loader.loadClip(target, holder_mc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SWF Tools **does** support AS3, you need to change it in the options.

```
1. Open your PDF in swf tools
2. Edit=>Options
3. Viewer tab
4. Check "No viewer" and flash version 9. (Or use the simple viewer) 
    - You can also do the "Insert stop after each frame"
```

I know this because I've done the same thing with a PDF. If you don't have those options, then it's time to download the latest version!